# Dynamic Programming Cheapest Train Ride Question

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, dynamic-programming

I am struggling with the below dynamic programming practice problem and I am hoping someone can help. The problem states:

*"You want to go from station 1 to station n by rail. The train fare from station i to station j is F(i, j). You want to break your trip up into a series of segments in order to minimize the cost, but each segment must go in the forward direction, i.e., from station i to station j for i < j.  Design an efficient dynamic programming algorithm for doing this and analyze its running time."*

Now, my thought would be that we would want to use a top-down approach. We start with some possible first choice from the starting station to some other station, then we recursively test all the different options. The recurrence relation would likely be something along the lines of picking the next possible segment that has the lowest fare.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should ask in Computer Science Stack Exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V(i)$ be the minimum cost to get from station $i$ to station $n$.  Then $V(n)=0$, and for $i<n$, the dynamic programming recursion ("Bellman's equation") is
$$V(i) = \min_{j>i} (F(i,j)+V(j)).$$
You want to compute $V(1)$, which you can do by computing $V(i)$ for $i=n$ to $1$ (in decreasing order of $i$).

Comment: Thanks for a quick hint! So might a good idea be to create a graph where each node is a station, and the forward-directed edges are the rails leading to the next station. The weight of each edge would then be the cost of the fare for that segment. Once we've done that, we could find the "shortest path from 1 to n" which would be lowest cost? Maybe use something like dijkstra's to solve this (or possibly bellman-ford if edge weights can be 0).

Comment: Yes, this is shortest path in a graph like you describe.  But the graph is directed acyclic, so Dijkstra and Bellman-Ford are overkill.  Just write down the dynamic programming recursion, and you can solve it on one pass.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks for that. So would you say that something like this could work? Say that I have F(n) = total fare and F(i,j) = fare from the previous station to the current station. So then our recurrence relation could be something like:

F(n) = min(F(i,j)) + F(i-1,j-1). 

My only concern with this is that i don't feel like it captures distance. For example, you could get 70 edges of cost 1 dollar, instead of getting the one edge from 1 to n of cost 6 dollars. Then the path selected will be much more expensive.

Comment: I would not use $F$ for two different things.  For the DP recursion, suppose you are at station $i$, and consider what choices you have available.

Comment: Well from a bottom-up approach, i would start at 1 and we'd have all stations from i to any subsequent station. So instead of F(n) I can say M(n) for minimum total fare, and then I could use C(i,j) as the cost of taking any arbitrary segment (i,j). So then I'd have M(n) = min(C(i,j)) + M(j). With this I am trying to say that the total cost M(n) is equal to the minimum of cost from segment i to j plus the total minimum cost from the remaining. Then it calls recursively on j.

Comment: You are close, but the LHS should be $M(i)$, and you should specify the indices for $\min$.  Also, $F$ was given, so don't change it to $C$.  Your $M$ is the same as my $V$.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "specify the indices for min" - my goal with that part (min(C(i,j))) is to illustrate we are taking the minimum far segment from i to some node j. Do you mean simply stating that 1 <= i < j <= n?

Comment: Yes, or even just $\min_{j>i}$.

Comment: Awesome. This makes a lot of sense now. Thank you very much for the guidance Rob!!